# Getting a column's IS_NULLABLE value from Simple.Data

Tags: simple.data

I'm using `Simple.Data.Ado.Schema.Column` to get the schema for the columns in my SQL Server database. But from browsing around the classes and going into the [source code](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data/blob/master/Simple.Data.SqlServer/SqlSchemaProvider.cs), it seems `Simple.Data` does not query for the `IS_NULLABLE` value.

Is there any way to retrieve from `Simple.Data` if a column is nullable or not? If not then I will probably need to modify the source code to include that info as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Simple.Data doesn't have any functionality that requires the nullable information, so it's not there.